# How to single out specific values in a matrix [R]

Tags: r, math, matrix, min

Hi i have a dilemma here. I have here with me a following matrix:

```
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
  [1,] 0.000000 1.414214 2.828427 4.242641 5.656854
  [2,] 1.414214 0.000000 1.414214 2.828427 4.242641
  [3,] 2.828427 1.414214 0.000000 1.414214 2.828427
  [4,] 4.242641 2.828427 1.414214 0.000000 1.414214
  [5,] 5.656854 4.242641 2.828427 1.414214 0.000000
```

My question here is how do I single out the least non-zero value in the matrix above. Clearly, if I used `min(A)` I would get 0 as my answer but what I want is the value `1.414214`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

min of a where a is not equal to 0

```
min(a[a!=0])
```

---

With a function to print index:

```
min_value <- function(M){
  
  minval <- min(M[M!=0])
  index <- which(M==minval, arr.ind=TRUE)
  
  print(paste("The smallest non-zero value (", minval, ") is located in:", sep=""))
  
  for(i in 1:nrow(index)){
    print(paste("row[", index[i, 1] ,"] and column[", index[i, 2], "]", sep="" ))
  }
  
  return(list(min_value=minval, index=index))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use  `tail()` together with `which`: here `mat` is your matrix

1. get the index `yourIndex` from the first non-zero value
2. then call the value in the matrix

```
yourIndex <- tail(which(mat!=0),1)
mat[yourIndex]

OR shorter:

mat[tail(which(mat!=0,1)
```

```
> mat[yourIndex]
[1] 1.414214
```

Comment: Is there a way I could put it inside a function and once I find the value, it will print the following words.  `print(The smallest non-zero value is located in column[j] and row[i]`.
It should work with all matrices and not just the one mentioned above. It is sorta like how in python you can print two things(a statement and a value) at once but this time I want it to like work automatically for any matrices

Answer (score 0):

Using a matrix you can do a simple for loop

```
min_numbers <- rep(NA,5)

for (i in 1:5){
  min_numbers[i] <- min(m[(m[,i] > 0),i])
}

min_numbers
```

But I would rather work with a data frame on `tydiverse`